# Combine subitems from list of items

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

i want to ask you for help with combine all subitems from list, which looks like:

```
public class Subitem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public List<Subitem> Subitems { get; set; }
}



var components = new List<Item>();
components.Add(new Item()
{
    Code = "ItemCode1",
    Name = "Item1Name",
    Subitems = new List<Subitem>
    {
        new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode1", Price = 32 },
        new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode2", Price = 21 },
        new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode3", Price = 11 },
        new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode4", Price = 51 }
    }
});
components.Add(new Item()
{
    Code = "ItemCode2",
    Name = "Item2Name",
    Subitems = new List<Subitem>
    {
        new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode5", Price = 11 },
        new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode6", Price = 22 },
        new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode7", Price = 52 },
        new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode8", Price = 63 }
    }
});
components.Add(new Item()
    {
        Code = "ItemCode3",
        Name = "Item3Name",
        Subitems = new List<Subitem>
        {
            new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode9", Price = 11 },
            new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode10", Price = 22 },
            new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode11", Price = 52 },
            new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode12", Price = 63 }
        }
    });
components.Add(new Item()
    {
        Code = "ItemCode4",
        Name = "Item4Name",
        Subitems = new List<Subitem>
        {
            new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode13", Price = 11 },
            new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode14", Price = 22 },
            new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode15", Price = 52 },
            new Subitem { Code = "SubitemCode16", Price = 63 }
        }
    });
```

I want to combine all subitems in model which looks like this:

```
new { Code = SubitemCode1, Price = 32 }
...
new { Code = SubitemCode8, Price = 63 }


new { Code = "SubitemCode1:SubitemCode5", Price = 43 } //11 + 32
...
new { Code = "SubitemCode1:SubitemCode8", Price = 95 } //32 + 63


new { Code = "SubitemCode2:SubitemCode5", Price = ... }
...
new { Code = "SubitemCode2:SubitemCode8", Price = ... }

@EDIT

new { Code = "SubitemCode1:SubitemCode5:SubitemCode9", Price = 54 } // 11 + 32 + 11
...
new { Code = "SubitemCode1:SubitemCode5:SubitemCode12", Price = 96 } // 11 + 32 + 63

new { Code = "SubitemCode1:SubitemCode6:SubitemCode9", Price = ... }
...
new { Code = "SubitemCode1:SubitemCode6:SubitemCode12", Price = ... }
...
new { Code = "SubitemCode1:SubitemCode8:SubitemCode9", Price = ... }
...
new { Code = "SubitemCode1:SubitemCode8:SubitemCode12", Price = ... }

new { Code = "SubitemCode2:SubitemCode5:SubitemCode9", Price = ... }
...
```

Can anyone explain to me how to get on with it? There could be 1-5 **Item** and 1-10 in **Subitems** in each **Item** and i need to have all combination of subitems with the addition of prices.

**Subitems** from **Item** in which they are, is not combinable, only **Subitems** from other **Item**

Thank You in Advance,

Best Regards.

Comment: Can you share your attempt to do this?

Comment: I don't even know how to start with it. I have idea to implement foreach in foreach (item1, subitem1, item2, subitem2,...) but the count of Item in list is not const. I need some hints on how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make join over two different list like

```
var result = components[0].Subitems
             .Join(components[1].Subitems, x => true, y => true, (a, b) => new { Code = a.Code + ":" + b.Code, Price = a.Price + b.Price })
             .ToList();
```

**OR** you can do this by using linq

```
var result = from a in components[0].Subitems
             from b in components[1].Subitems
             select new
             {
                 Code = a.Code + ":" + b.Code,
                 Price = a.Price + b.Price
             };
```

And finally print the result

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
      Console.WriteLine("Code: " + item.Code + "\t Price: " + item.Price);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but count of item in List is not const. There could be more than two Item in List<Item>, then your code will won't work

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i think that i got this.

The code looks like:

```
var result = new List<SubItem>(); //list of combined SubItems

var ms = 0; // start index of items from list to combine
var mk = 0; // end index of items from list to combine

for (int i = 0; i < components.Count; i++) // count of all items
{
    if (i == 0) //if there is a first item then we don't combine codes and prices
    {
        for (int mat = 0; mat < components[i].SubItems.Count; mat++)
        {
            var data = components[i].SubItem[mat];
            result.Add(new SubItem { Price = data.Price, Code = data.Code });
            mk = mat; // set last index of SubItem to combine
        }
        continue;
    }

    for (int j = ms; j < mk + 1; j++) // iterate from first to last SubItem to combine them with new SubItems 
    {
        for (int mat = 0; mat < components[i].SubItems.Count; mat++) // iterate through SubItems
        {
            result.Add(new SubItem { Code = result[j].Code + ":" + components[i].SubItem[mat].Code, price = result[j].Price + components[i].SubItem[mat].Price }); // Combine last SubItem with now iterating Subitem.
        }
    }

    ms = mk + 1; // update new start index to combine
    mk = result.Count - 1; // update new end index to combine
}
```

I achieved what I wanted. :)

Best Regards!